# Vista: Determining corresponding process of a window

Tags: windows-vista, malware

There is some kind of malware installed on a client's computer.  It effectively prevents the administrator account from being used.

It pops up a fullscreen window which you can't get around:  Alt+Tab does show the list of windows, but switching doesn't work.  You can start the task manager, but it loses focus.  However, ordinary user accounts seem not to be affected.  I tried to find out the malicous process using processexplorer while simultaneously logged into another user account--but couldn't find any suspicous processes.

Is it possible to find out which process has opended that window while logged into another user account?  The drag&drop inspector, which comes with processexplorer of course doesn't work, because you can't move the mouse to another session :-)

Comment: If you are unable to make the task manager the focused application it will be tough. My suggestion, backup the files, and format the computer.  You can also create a new admin user...

Comment: @Ramhound Thanks Ramhound. I reinstalled windows.  Can't believe how windows sucks.